# How to delete the key of the object based on user input?

Tags: javascript

I have an object which basically consists of some of the names of cars. I just want to **delete the key of that object** based on user input.

For instance:

```js
let cars = {
  car1: 'BMW',
  car2: 'Lambo',
  car3: 'Mercedes'
};

const deleteCar = (car) => {
  delete cars.car;
}

deleteCar('car1');
console.log(cars);
```

As you can see, it doesn't actually delete the key from the object. How can I do this?

Comment: You'd be able to delete the property using `delete cars[car]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bracket (`[]`) notation which allows us to dynamically access property names:

```js
let cars = {
  car1: 'BMW',
  car2: 'Lambo',
  car3: 'Mercedes'
};

const deleteCar = (car) => {
  delete cars[car];
}

deleteCar('car1');
console.log(cars);
```

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks

Comment: @Sanjay, you are most welcome....

Answer (score 1):

`foo.bar` in JavaScript is equivalent to `foo["bar"]`. Thus, if `car` is a string, `delete cars[car]` does the correct thing (while `delete cars.car` tries to delete the literal key `"car"`, which you don't have).

Comment: Thank you! Got it